# Delete mysql data with input

Tags: php, mysql

Im makeing something new but i want to make delete file where you can type ID and then click on submit and this function deletes the data from mysql.

**Delete.php**

```html
<?php
  ob_start();
  include("db.php");
  if(isset($_GET['id'])!="")
  {
  $delete=$_GET['id'];
  $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM Osebe WHERE id='$OsebaID'");
  if($delete)
  {
      header("Location:index.php");
  }
  else
  {
      echo mysql_error();
  }
  }
  ob_end_flush();
?>
```

html file with form

```html
<html>
 <head>
 
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> TEST </title>
  <style>
</style>
 
  <!-- STYLES -->
  <link href="css/dodaj.css" rel="stylesheet">
 
 </head>
<body>

 
<div class="login">
<h1> IZBRIŠI VNOS </h1>
  <FORM ACTION="brisi.php" method="post"><br>
  ID: <input type=text name="id"><br>
  <input type=submit value"Delete"><input type=reset value="Ponastavi>
  </form>
  
  
  </div>
  


</body>

</html>
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: This `if(isset($_GET['id'])!="")` will probably work not like you expect. Isset returns boolean true or false which is then compared to an empty string.

Comment: and do not use deprecated mysql_* functions

Comment: Debug you code using check where the problem is and mention here if you have an particular error.

Comment: In addition to the mismatch between submission methods described in the answers from sgt BOSE and Viky. .... do you really mean `WHERE id='$OsebaID'"` or do you want to delete the ID passed from the form? (in which case, in addition to the logic error there is an SQL injection vuln).

Answer (score 2):

You are passing value in **post** and getting that value in **get** you have typo within your query

Try

```
if(!empty($_POST['id']))
  {
  $delete = $_POST['id'];
  $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM Osebe WHERE id='$OsebaID'");
}
```

> You were using deprecated **mysql** switch to **PDO** or **mysqli**

Answer (score 0):

It should be `post` not `get` as your `form` `method` is set to `post`. Try this -

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])!="")
{
  $delete=$_POST['id'];
  $delete=mysql_query("DELETE FROM Osebe WHERE id='$OsebaID'");

  ...............
```

> Try to use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of `mysql` extension.